# What are the differences between building with a MERN stack vs Laravel (with React) for a web application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, laravel, react-native, mern

What are the differences (pros and cons) between building with a MERN stack vs Laravel (with React) for a web application?

**MERN:**

**MongoDB:** A document-based open source database.
**Express.js** A web application framework for Node.js
**React** A JavaScript front-end library for building user interfaces.
**Node.js** A JavaScript run-time environment that executes JavaScript code outside of a browser (such as a server).

vs.

**Laravel (PHP)** with React

Comment: Minimal, or enormous. Depends quite a bit on you, and what you do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The principal difference is that you learn two languages with the second option if your questions are about performance, no trouble if you know how to configure with the perfect way a server for PHP, but all depends for your requirements if you want to find developers that maintain your apps, or you want to scale the app, Laravel is a great framework and you can use Mongo with him, for tastes there are colors